How to use excel files on SharePoint as data sources for power bi without hardcoded paths
I have a dashboard that fetches data from an excel files in SharePoint. To fetch the data from SharePoint I have to hardcode the paths to these excel folders in our SharePoint.
The dashboard works, but I know that my organization is planning on restructuring the SharePoint and I don’t want all the dashboards to break because the path no longer matches exactly.
Is there any way I can have the excel files be stored in a shared location but not use a hardcoded path?
How I get the data right now:

Source = Excel.Workbook( 
    SharePoint.Contents("https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/ORG-BRANCH") 
        {[Name="Dashboards"]}[Content] 
        {[Name="Accomplishments"]}[Content] 
        // … 
        {[Name="input.xlsx"]}[Content] ) 


As you can see, any changes to the file_name in {[Name="file_name"]}[Content] would result SharePoint site structure would result in the data not being found by Power Bi.
I have used Microsoft lists in the past which work very well, but it's hard to enter the amount of data that excel can process into lists so I would like to avoid doing that.

So is the issue the file name changes or that the sharepoint site is changing? If the name changes how would you determine what is the right file via logic? For example, do they add a date or version to the end of the file name or something? A floating file name or website I feel like probably wouldn't work as anticipated unless its systematic on how things can change.

Both really, the dashboard is dependent on the SharePoint site and the file name matching what the path given in M language. changes to the site or the file name will cause the dashboard to break, although I think breaking when the file name changes is much more acceptable than breaking where there is a change in the path to the excel spreadsheet.

So why don't you make those two components inputs on a cell somewhere so you don't need to dive into the M to fix it? Seems easier to maintain and again to make these floating I imagine you'll spend more time chasing your tail

I like the idea of using cells to store the location of the file, unfortunately I’m on a non-technical team with very little familiarity with power Bi and I’m not confident someone else on the team would be able to identify what went wrong if the path changed, let alone that changing some seemingly random cell values fixes the issue.
That being said, I’m having some success storing the model in power bi service then taking data from there. I’ll make sure to keep this thread updated. Still very open to suggestions though and super thankful for the feedback received so far.

If this is for Powerbi, you could have a static spreadsheet somewhere static where you input these cells and point those to that in power query as a single input. Then you refer to that in the M statement. There's a lot of documentation online on how to point a power query to a cell on a spreadsheet. Focus less on "something went wrong the link changed" if you have a process on how to fix. So it becomes "just update this file with the new link", annoying, but temporary while IT figures why the link changes.

But if you have another solution that solves the issue you are able to post an answer for yourself so it's all documented. Just be extremely thorough in that component so others can find it helpful as well!

Oh yes, I have used M language extensively and personally prefer coding to modeling, I just feel I might have written myself into a corner where anything else I add to power Bi will just make the dashboard more difficult for my team maintain.
In any case the current method of storing an excel file on SharePoint feels a little hacky to begin with and I was wondering if there were any good alternatives.

A formal database is definitely the better alternative to feeding a powerbi dashboard.

After some experimentation with Power BI service, It is possible to upload an excel dataset to power bi service which can be edited using excel. Using a semantic model to pull the data into the dashboard would allow you to bypass SharePoint, treating the dataset as a “data mart” that can be updated at any time. This process needs a Power Bi premium license however, and so this was not a viable solution for me, but it might be the solution for anyone else who encounters this issue.
Import Excel workbooks into Power BI Desktop - Power BI | Microsoft Learn
Another solution, as Mark S suggested data should always live on a database, as such creating a Power App to manipulate a database full of data then pull data into the dashboard from that database is another possible solution, unfortunately one that will not work for me as well.
Connect to SQL Server from Power Apps - Power Apps | Microsoft Learn
Create an app to edit tables in canvas apps - Power Apps | Microsoft Learn
In the end I decided to write additional documentation including information on identifying when there is a disconnect between the hardcoded path and the excel file along with instructions on how to fix it. It’s not a perfect solution but it will at least be better than having the dashboard randomly break when the path to the excel file changes.
